# Improving Cell Signal to Increase Data Speeds

Tags: data-wiring, internet

I just moved to a very rural area in Western WA  on the top of a hill. My internet options are very slow (< 3Mb/s) DSL, Sat, and using my cell provider (Verizon Wireless) for internet. The last option is what I primarily use, however, the signal is somewhat weak inside the house and my data connection becomes very slow. I can put my phone up against certain windows on the upper floor and that dramatically improves the signal and data transfer speeds, so I'm trying to come up with a way to effectively boost the signal without the need to keep my phone pinned against a window.

What is the best way to boost the signal? I don't care so much about calls, which work fine, but trying to boost the 4G LTE signal/data transfer speed. An effective method for me could be using some kind of antenna and amplifier into a Wifi router.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There are a number of cell phone booster options on the market. Bestbuy has a few. IF there is more than one of you, go for the ones that have a rooftop antenna and boost your whole house / yard.

Comment: Like in my answer here.. http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/109515/get-phone-signal-where-theres-no-signal/109520#109520

Comment: The walls themselves will block enough signal that in cases like this I always recommend something with an external antenna. Next, make sure it's powered to boost the signal. Unpowered can only help in places where the signal is marginal at best. Wifi is not the same thing and a wifi repeater will not help a cell signal

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because cellphone boosting isn't Home Improvement.

Comment: If you vote to close this question, please suggest an alternative place for the question, don't just close it.

Comment: @DanielGriscom I don't know, these days data communication is pretty integral to home life. If the solution is placing an appropriate antenna on the roof and getting a 4G LTE adapter of some kind, that kind of sounds like home improvement to me?  :)

Comment: @HighwayofLife It's unfortunate, but true, that the Stack Exchange sites do not cover all areas of knowledge. Specifically, I don't know a better place to put this question.